# Prebinding using websocket xmpp

Tags: websocket, xmpp

Is it possible to prebind by using websocket or using xep 0198?

I know in BOSH it is possible by using sid and attach it in every request

My scenario:

Login in top or parent website get session from ejabberd, so my chat client side will login automatically using session , so i dont put any password in javascript side

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not generally possible. Websocket sessions do not get a sid/rid assigned to them, as those are only used by BOSH.

Prebinding can be done in a single HTTP request though, so I don't see a need to use websocket.

Comment: Is there alternative using websocket for session? Cause i want to use websocket , it is faster than bosh..

Comment: Why do you think it is faster than BOSH? Have you measured it?

Comment: Yes it is more faster than bosh

Comment: How much faster? I'd be interested in seeing your results.